# Can I post photos and videos to Instagram using my app?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to make the app that will just post videos and images to Instagram BUT this will not be done automatically. It will be like normal post dialog like in Instagram app.

However my question is if I'm going to use that will it be attempt to replace the essential user experience of Instagram.com or the Instagram apps.
Regards, divjad---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link to the api docs for Instagram, though on quick inspection, it looks like it can handle uploads of images, though it doesn't mention video. Either way, it should tell you everything you need to know in here.

Please see links below

[Instagram Developer's page for the api](http://instagram.com/developer/)

[Instagram Developer's page specific to iOS and Android](http://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/)